# pushing openshift app to github for parallel development

Tags: github, openshift

I have cloned the app from openshift in my machine. We have other developers working on the app so we wanted to push the openshift app to github so all of us can work on that and deploy the final code in openshift.

the clone i have is tracking remote from openshift, how can i push this to github for others to clone?
Sorry I new to git and openshift and looking for some suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your github repo as a remote to your local Openshift repo

```
git remote add <some_name> <link to Github repo>
```

Or you can do it the other way around. Clone your github repo to your machine and then add your Openshift repo as a remote.

Comment: how do i push code both to github and openshift then? git remote show origin is showing fetch/ push URL to openshift alone

Comment: You can specify different remotes specifically whenever you do a push or pull, e.g. `git push upstream master` pushes your current branch to the master branch of the remote repo named upstream.